# Can't run SQL script in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a table named `account_`in my PostgreSQL with its fields. You can see it on pic.
[image]

When I try to execute script from file it shows me an error that `mvccversion fields doesn't exists in account_ table`

Here my file with script that I want to run

```
    SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION 'postgres';
SET search_path = public;
--
-- Data for blobs (OID = 28988) (LIMIT 0,1)
--
INSERT INTO account_ ("MVCCVERSION", "ACCOUNTID", "COMPANYID", "USERID", "USERNAME", "CREATEDATE", "MODIFIEDDATE", "PARENTACCOUNTID", "NAME", "LEGALNAME", "LEGALID", "LEGALTYPE", "SICCODE", "TICKERSYMBOL", "INDUSTRY", "TYPE_", "SIZE_") VALUES (11, 208, 206, 0, NULL, '03.04.2017 13:17:53', '02.03.2015 10:31:12', 0, 'TEST', 'TEST', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
COMMIT;
--
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Remove the double quotes and/or make the column names lower case.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, but does it matter type of case?

Comment: Postgres columns, when _not_ quoted, are folded to lower case.  But since you used the names in quotes, they will retain their original case, which doesn't match your table definition, and therefore is wrong.

Comment: Also, you may have to specify the database where your table appears, i.e. use `INSERT INTO yourDB.account_ (...)`

Comment: ok. I'll try it right now